# Resource URl Not Found with Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I wish to grab the historical stock price from Yahoo Finance into Google Sheet and received this error. Please assist.  If using import xml, how will it be?

https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX.AX/history?p=ASX.AX

```
=IMPORTHTML(D7,"table",1)
```

[image: Import HTML]

Comment: Does it have to come from Yahoo? Google has a built in =googlefinance() function (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the table from the URL of `https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX.AX/history?p=ASX.AX` and put it to the Spreadsheet.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that the table cannot be retrieved using IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML from the URL. This has already been mentioned in [Jason E.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66608544/7108653).

But, fortunately, when I tested to retrieve the table using UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script, I confirmed that the table can be retrieved. So, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, run the function of `myFunction` and please authorize the scopes. By this flow, the table is retrieved from the URL and put it to the active sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX.AX/history?p=ASX.AX";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const tables = res.getContentText().match(/(<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>)/g);
  if (!tables || tables.length == 0) throw new Error("No tables. Please confirm URL again.");
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  const resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: tables[0], coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}}}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheet.getId());
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the URL of `https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX.AX/history?p=ASX.AX`. So when you changed the URL, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: @Jia Wei Yeap By the way, if to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script is not the direction you expected, I have to apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo seems to have made some changes to their website resulting for the IMPORT functions of Google Sheet not to work. This affected some(not all) of their webpage as well as the tickers. Using IMPORTXML will still give you the same error.

[image]

I suggest using the built in GOOGLEFINANCE() function or find another website that is **scrape-able** by IMPORT functions and will give you the same data as you wanted.

Comment: I avoid google finance is because ASX stocks has 3 decimals places which Google Finance round it to 2. Need to find the MA for the past 10 days

Comment: You can try manually calculating the price using googlefinance marketcap/shares and round the result to 3 decimal places. `=ROUND(GOOGLEFINANCE("asx:asx", "marketcap")/GOOGLEFINANCE("asx:asx", "shares"), 3)`

Comment: Using that method that you recommend, what if i wish to obtain the stock prices for the past 5 days, how shall i do so ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the method I recommended is not usable if dealing with historical data.